# How to add and subtract values from an average?

Tags: average

Say I have 100 numbers that are averaged:

```
number of values = 100
total sum of values = 2000
mean = 2000 / 100 => 20
```

If I want to add a value and find out the new average:

```
total sum of values = 2000 + 100
mean = 2100 / 101 => 20.79
```

If I want to subtract a value and find out the new average:

```
total sum of values = 2100 - 100
mean = 2000 / 100 => 20
```

It seems to work, but is the above correct?

Is this the proper way to add/subtract values from a average without having to re-sum all the 100 numbers first?

Answer (score 37, accepted):

$s=\frac{a_1+...+a_n}{n}$.

If you want the average of $a_1,...,a_n$ and $a_{n+1}$, then $s'=\frac{a_1+...+a_n+a_{n+1}}{n+1}=\frac{ns+a_{n+1}}{n+1} = \frac{(n+1)s+a_{n+1}}{n+1} - \frac{s}{n+1} = s + \frac{a_{n+1}-s}{n+1}$

If you want the average of $a_1,...,a_{n-1}$ then $s''=\frac{a_1+...+a_{n-1}}{n-1}=\frac{ns-a_n}{n-1}= \frac{(n-1)s-a_n}{n-1} + \frac{s}{n-1}=s+\frac{s-a_n}{n-1}$.

Comment: And $ns$ is the old sum, as you can derive from the first equation.

Comment: I'm tempted to downvote as ns is not explained in the answer

Comment: At first I commented that @501's answer was clearer but realized I didn't fully understand why the question worked. This answer, while denser, actually explains the result.

Comment: @Celeritas $ns = n \cdot s$, $n$ and $s$ are defined quantities in the post.

Comment: This is the working answer. @501's answer doesn't work when increasing `n` by more than 1.

Answer (score 82):

I know that's an old thread but I had the same problem.
I want to add a value to an existing average without calculate it back to the total sum.

to add an value to an exisitng average we only must know for how much values the average is calculated:
$$
average_{new} = average_{old} +  \frac{ value_{new} - average_{old}}{size_{new}}
$$

Comment: I may be a smart guy, but the accepted answer above was incomprehensible to me. This answer works perfectly, and I can understand it. Thanks!

Comment: @501 - not implemented thank you!

Comment: This answer was exactly what I needed. Elegant!

Comment: -1 Careful this formula works only for adding `1` new value! Please work out the correct equation using this answer and you'll see! https://math.stackexchange.com/a/1153800/503549

Comment: Is it possible to calculate median in a similar way?

Comment: @kouton why would you downvote for an answer that only works for adding one value when the requirement was "...to add A value..." (emphasis added). If I ask you to run a mile and you run a mile, I'm not going to penalize you for not running two miles.

Answer (score 26):

To put it programmatically, and since the question was about how to both *add* and *subtract*:

Add a value:

```
average = average + ((value - average) / nValues)
```

Subtract a value:

```
average = (average * nValues - value) / (nValues - 1)
```

Comment: Oh thank god there's another programmer on here. Those math equations make my head hurt.

Comment: @MattD: see also [this answer on StackOverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/a/22999488/1269037) for replacing a number in a running average.

Comment: Shouldn't the first formula end with `/ nValues + 1)` rather than `/ nValues)`?

Answer (score 3):

Another formula can be

$$\text{NewAvg} = \frac{( \text{OldAvg} \cdot \text{OldSize} ) + \text{NewValue} } { \text{NewSize}}$$

Comment: I was looking for this answer. It's intuitive because `newAvg = (sum + newValue) / newSize` (by definition of average). And also by definition `sum = avg * size`.

Comment: And also easy for multiple values: `newAvg = (sum1 + sum2) / (size1 + size2)`. Or in the other format `newAvg = (avg1 * size1 + avg2 * size2) / (size1 + size2)`.